# I'm getting a Error using node package mysql v2.16.0 while connecting to database Error: Packets out of order. Got: 80 Expected: 0

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

versions:

- node                > 11.4.0
- mysql(node package) > 2.16.0
- phpMyAdmin          > 4.8.3
- MySQL               > 5.7

I'm using this code:

```
const mysql = require('mysql');

let db = mysql.createConnection({
  host:'hidden',
  port:'hidden',
  user:'hidden',
  password:'hidden',
  database: 'hidden',
  dubug: true
});

sqlfn.createTable('Internal', db, 'test_table', (result, err) => {
  if(err) {console.log(err.stack); return};
  console.log('Create OK: ', result);
});
```

From the function file sqlfn:

```
exports.createTable = (req, db, name, callback) => {
  let query_string = String(`CREATE TABLE ${name} (uid VARCHAR(255), name VARCHAR(255), type VARCHAR(255), data VARCHAR(255), modified VARCHAR(255))`);

  db.query(query_string, (err, result) => {
      if(err) fn.logit(req, 'SQL', 'error', `in <createTable> ${err}`);

      callback(result, err);
  });
};
```

This is the error that I am getting:

> >
>   Error: Packets out of order. Got: 80 Expected: 0
>       at Parser.write (C:\Users\hidden\Documents\Git\hidden\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:42:19)
>       at Protocol.write (C:\Users\hidden\Documents\Git\hidden\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:38:16)
>       at Socket. (C:\Users\hidden\Documents\Git\hidden\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:91:28)
>       at Socket. (C:\Users\hidden\Documents\Git\hidden\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:502:10)
>       at Socket.emit (events.js:189:13)
>       at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:288:12)
>       at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:269:11)
>       at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:224:10)
>       at TCP.onStreamRead [as onread] (internal/stream_base_commons.js:145:17)
>       --------------------
>       at Protocol._enqueue (C:\Users\hidden\Documents\Git\hidden\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:144:48)    at Protocol.handshake (C:\Users\hidden\Documents\Git\hidden\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:51:23)    at Connection.connect (C:\Users\hidden\Documents\Git\hidden\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:118:18)
>       at Connection._implyConnect (C:\Users\hidden\Documents\Git\hidden\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:453:10)    at Connection.query (C:\Users\hidden\Documents\Git\hidden\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:198:8)
>       at Object.exports.createTable (C:\Users\hidden\Documents\Git\hidden\components\functions\sql.js:36:8)
>       at Object. (C:\Users\hidden\Documents\Git\hidden\components\controllers\controll_admin.js:22:7)
>       at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:30)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:734:10)
>       at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:620:32)

If anyone know how i can fix or work-around this I'd love some feedback and help regarding this.

thank you.
:)

Comment: Are you using the correct port?  https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql/issues/1890

Comment: yes, i am using the correct port.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error and it was because I was not setting the correct port for my database which was 3305 instead of the default 3306

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution. Also remember: as soon as you have the necessary reputation you can also post smaller hints as a comment.